# Retrieve data sent by xmlhttprequest in cakephp's controller

Tags: cakephp, xmlhttprequest, cakephp-2.0

I want to send some data (image,text,...) to Posts controller :

```
    $('#home').click(function (){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST","/Portfilo/posts/test",true);
        xhr.send("id=10");
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
            {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
```

test action is :

```
    public function test()
    {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        //$id = $this->params['named']['id'];


        if($this->request->named){
            echo "Yesssssss";
        }
        else {
            echo 'Oh No';
        }

    }
```

how I cane retrieve these data from this connection (xmlhttprequest).

I read [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html)  article but functions or properties like these :

```
// Passed arguments

$this->request->pass;

$this->request['pass'];

$this->request->params['pass'];
```

Or

```
// named parameters

$this->request->named;
```

return to me ***"Oh Noooo"*** message.

How to retrieve these parameter and data s from this request?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending data through `POST` method to the `test` action, you can retrieve it using `$this->request->data` array, which will contain all variables sent by `POST`.

In your case, you can try this:

```
public function test(){
        $this->layout = 'ajax';

        if($this->request->data['id']){
            echo "Yesssssss";
        }
        else {
            echo 'Oh No';
        }
}
```

Comment: ...... </code></span></pre><pre class="stack-trace">PostsController::test() - APP\Controller\PostsController.php, line 41
ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs() - [internal], line ?? ...

I receive this error when call $this->request->data['id']; or another function in my question;

Comment: It might be that you are not sending the data through `POST` method. What you can do to figure out where is the data you want to retrieve, is printing all the `$this->request->data` array and look for your variables or values. Then you will see inside which key they are.

Comment: xhr.open("POST","/Portfilo/posts/test",true);
        xhr.send("id=10");
mentioned above.

Comment: As I said, print the result of `$this->request->data` array and try to find your variables/values